# Alguém pode ajudar a escrever este programa em python que envolve tuplos?

Tags: python, funções

Estou a escrever a função "verifica" em python, que recebe um argumento de qualquer tipo e devolve True se esse argumento for um tuplo cujos elementos são pares (duplos de 2 elementos), em que o 1º elemento é um nome (uma cadeia de caracteres) e o 2º elemento é uma idade (um inteiro). Em caso contrário devolve False. Foi a isto que chguei:

```
def verifica(variavel):
    if isinstance(variavel, tuple):
        if isinstance(variavel[0], str) and isinstance(variavel[1], int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

O resultado deverá ser por exemplo:

```
>>> verifica( (('Maria', 38), ('Miguel', 17), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19)) )
>>> True

>>> verifica( ((54, 38), ('Miguel', 17), ('Tiago', 18), ('Sara', 19)) )
>>> False
```

Não estou a conseguir obter este resultado, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Essa pergunta já foi feita, como pode perceber, mas gostaria de salientar que seu primeiro exemplo está errado. A função não deve retornar `True` se a entrada for uma tupla que contém 4 tuplas. O próprio texto da pergunta é bastante claro: **só deve retornar true se for uma tupla com 2 valores, sendo uma string e um inteiro**.

Comment: Sim, a pergunta já foi feita, mas as soluções indicadas não são aquela que é procurada.´, daí estar a tentar procurar ajuda também, obrigado se puder dar alguma indicação agradecia.

Comment: Talvez não a procurada, mas foi respondido exatamente o que foi perguntado. Se as soluções lá não atendem, recomendo que você edite a pergunta e detalhe melhor o que deverá ser feito. Inclusive o código que postou parece ser o mesmo que outro usuário respondeu lá, então busque sempre dar os devidos créditos. Você pode ler outros detalhes no Termo de Serviço do site.

Comment: A resposta da outra pergunta foi editada. Verifica lá se te ajuda.

Comment: Não é aquela solução que pretendo, mas muito obrigado :) O que procuro é algo como: def verifica(variavel): for all tuplos
    #If para saber se é uma tupla

    if type(variavel) is tuple:
        #Caso seja tupla, vamos verificar se o primeiro elemento é str e o segundo int
        if (type(variavel[0]) is str) and (type(variavel[1]) is int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return False